# Database output to number

Tags: ruby

I pulled a number from a database, using the following code:

```
@all = @m.query("SELECT * FROM OR_TEST3").fetch_row
@count = @all.at(4)
```

However, this gives me @count="1", instead of @count=1, which doesn't work, because I need to use @count to specify the iterations in a "for" loop.  Is there an easy way to make @count a normal number?  Sorry, I am new to Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert string to a number with `to_i` method

```
@count = @all.at(4).to_i
```

How are you learning ruby? Every tutorial and book should have this covered.

Comment: Thank!  I have a background in R, and I've gone over Ruby tutorials, but I haven't had the time to focus on each piece like I should.  Maybe this winter I'll be able to get around to it.